# axios doesn't send post for Stripe

Tags: express, axios, stripe-payments

I have a problem with axios Post. I work on adding Stripe payment to my page, but i send me axios error 404.

Maybe somebody can help me, I stuck on it for week already and cant just solve it.
Here is the code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from "axios";

const Pay = () => {
    const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null)
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const onToken = (token) => {
        setStripeToken(token);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        const makeRequest = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.post(
                    "http//:localhost:5001/api/checkout/payment",
                    {
                        tokenId: stripeToken.id,
                        amount: 6000,
                    });
                console.log(res.data)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        };
        stripeToken && makeRequest()
    }, [stripeToken]);

return (
        <div className='pay__div'>

            {stripeToken ? (<span>Processing</span>) : (
                <StripeCheckout
                    name="Kate store"
                    image=""
                    billingAddress
                    shippingAddress
                    description="Yout total is $60"
                    amount={2000}
                    token={onToken}
                    stripeKey={KEY}
                >

                    <button>Pay</button>
                </StripeCheckout>
            )}

        </div>
    )
}

export default Pay
```

Thank you for your time.

Also here are stripe.js index.js pages from backend

stripe.js

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);

router.post("/payment", (req, res) => {
    stripe.charges.create({
        sourse: req.body.tokenId,
        amount: req.body.amount,
        currency: "usd"
    },
        (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
            if (stripeErr) {
                res.status(500).json(stripeErr);
            } else {
                res.status(200).json(stripeRes);
            }
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const userRoute = require("./routes/user");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const productRoute = require("./routes/product");
const cartRoute = require("./routes/cart");
const orderRoute = require("./routes/order");
const stripeRoute = require("./routes/stripe");

const cors = require("cors");

dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
    .then(() => console.log("DB Connected Successfull!"))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/user", userRoute); 
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/product", productRoute);
app.use("/api/cart", cartRoute);
app.use("/api/order", orderRoute);
app.use("/api/checkout", stripeRoute);


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5001, () => {
    console.log("Backend is running")
})
```

Comment: Is http//:localhost:5001/ your api server working? Please provide more information.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, yes localhost:5001 is working. But page which I used in axios : constres=awaitaxios.post("http://localhost:5001/api/checkout/payment"   says Cannot GET /api/checkout/payment

Comment: also when I try to make a payment on my frontend page http://localhost:3000/pay xhr.js:221     it gives me error :    POST http://localhost:5001/api/checkout/payment 500 (Internal Server Error)   AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Comment: if it is 500, maybe the problem is at the backend

Comment: I am sorry for terrible formating of the code

Comment: Thank you so much Phil, sorry first time here and just found how to put everything readible. Added code of backend as well in the question.

Comment: Given your backend literally responds with `res.status(500).json(stripeErr);`, have you tried looking at the response body? I would also advise adding `console.error(stripeErr)` to your Express code so it logs the actual problem

Comment: Thank you so much Phil for responding. I have these errors in console : `xhr.js:221          POST http://localhost:3000/http//:localhost:5001/api/checkout/payment 404 (Not Found)` and `AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}` .

Comment: Your URL syntax is incorrect. You have `http//:` where it should be `http://`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Moved `dotenv.config();` before `const stripeRoute = require("./routes/stripe");` in index.js and worked.